# Symbian get content-type?

Tags: c++, http-headers, symbian, content-type, carbide

I'm develop on C++ for Symbian. How do I get the content-type from the site I'm accessing from RHTTPTransaction?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get the `RHTTPResponse` object from the transaction with `Response()` and then access the `Content-Type` header value via `GetHeaderCollection()` and `GetField()`.